# kvm bridges: disable promiscuous mode, is it possible and is it wise?

Tags: centos, linux-networking, cisco, kvm-virtualization, switch

I am a little confused as to if this is the right question, but I have a number of KVM hosts with multiple bridges on (sometimes)bonded interfaces, and each bridge is mapped to its own distinct VLAN.
(A KVM host can have possibly a router guest, a load balancer guest, and maybe a dns server, and internal server guests on them, each to its own bridge).

KVM host OSes are CentOS 6-8. Guests are any Linux OS that is necessary. The network switches are Cisco 2960s, configured with trunks for the KVM hosts connections.

Ive noticed when I am doing things like tcpdump, or even looking at traffic between internal and external switches, I find MAC addresses and internal IPs that I feel shouldn't be visible.
(eg, some of the kvm guests are routers, and are bridged to VLANs that have access to an external switch, in order to reach internet/external resources, and some are load balancers, and some run NTOPNG/traffic sniffers).

In effect guests on different VLAN bridges can see/receive traffic not meant for them, and I see internal traffic on external switches.
Is there a way of preventing the guests from seeing traffic not meant for their bridge? Is this wise?

Comment: `some of the kvm guests are routers, and are bridged to VLANs` Note that using a bridge for a bunch of VMs / an "internal" network does NOT require you to enslave a physical NIC to that bridge. Also, one VM can be connected to multiple bridges. You should have only VMs that serves as a gateway/router bridged to a "external" bridge (and an internal bridge). You do NOT need to enslave a physical NIC to an "internal" bridge either if the VM host is supposed to be the gateway. In such case you should make use of IP forwarding on the host (just like you would make use of that on a router VM).

Comment: Besides, there's iptables / ebtables or nftables.

Comment: Thanks but it’s a mixed bag, which happened due to insane deadlines and heavy management push to ‘get things done now’ and insane choices on hardware and planning. So I have a mixed bag of vms in different VLANs doing multiple things on multiple kvm hosts, some needing internet access (load balancers and routers), some handling inter-VLAN routing, and some just being servers, all communicating on the same switches. It’s really bad. So I was wondering how to limit some traffic leakage from the kvm hosts.